# Modify typescript type of list to create a key value type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

While recently playing around with typescript type manipulation I tried to modify the type below

```js
type setOfFunctions = [{
    name: 'hi',
    fun: () => number
}, {
    name: 'world',
    fun: () => string
}]
```

to archive the following type

```js
type MyFunctions = {
    hi: () => number,
    world: () => string
}
```

I tried with the following type

```js
type MyFunctions = {
    [key in setOfFunctions[number]["name"]] : setOfFunctions[number]["fun"]
}
```

But that ends up with

```js
type MyFunctions = {
    hi: (() => number) | (() => string);
    world: (() => number) | (() => string);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current implementation `setOfFunctions[number]["fun"]` will get both of the types in one, need to filter it somehow.

I have this.

Using a "filter" with a generic and an `extends` operation, if there is a match with the current key, infer the type of the function and use it as the value.

If theres no match just discard the function type with `never`

```
type setOfFunctions = [{
    name: 'hi',
    fun: () => number
}, {
    name: 'world',
    fun: () => string
}]

type getPropertieFnType<T extends setOfFunctions[number], key extends string> = T extends { name: key, fun: infer K } ? K : never

type MyFunctions  = {
    [key in setOfFunctions[number]["name"]]: getPropertieFnType<setOfFunctions[number], key>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzhwHkBmAxArgOwMbAJYHsMYoBeKAbQG8BYAKCgagwEMBbCALigHIALXbgBo6jKEkxcAFAEpSAPiZpWAIwgAnOgF9BUGvUYt2XbgHd8agDYATISMbiMU2SQUxga3BgDmWgLp06UEgoL3gABTV8SDU8CBQMABVwCAAeBKgIAA9gCAwrYjhEVEwcAiJyDCVVNV8dAGsIEAzs3PzYd08vBTJ0rJy84komNk4oBpAdBy5PJHUoAGkoTSgAfgWoLgwIADd1ANog6ABZEHRsPEJiUl07BnJxqE9YeGQz0suKqvVfcgAiQwgv18vi4oWAESi6li8SSkBShVeJQu5UqKm%209Uaci0dCAA)